# Objective C: Expression is not assignable when using bracket syntax, but works when dot syntax is used

Tags: objective-c

So, I have the following method:

```
- (void)setContainedItem:(BNRItem *)item
{
    _containedItem = item;
    [item container] = self;
}
```

This results in an error that says: Expression is not assignable.  However
using the dot syntax works:

```
- (void)setContainedItem:(BNRItem *)item
{
    _containedItem = item;
    item.container = self;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
[item setContainer:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign values to a method call this way. You need to call the method and provide the value as an attribute.

Properties (that is using the dot syntax) always call the appropriate getter and setters whose default name is 'something' (getter) and 'setSomething' (setter.